# Maven: compiling and testing on different source levels

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, mockito

I am currently working on a project which will run on an embedded device. The device runs a Java ME JRE (comparable to Java 1.4).

Because of this maven is configured to compile for source & target level 1.4.

Is it possible to run the maven test phase on a different source/target level? Because this way I could use Mockito for unit-testing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The source and target versions can be set separately for the [compile](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#source) and [testCompile](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile-mojo.html#testSource) goals of the [maven compiler plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/). You can change the settings either by defining properties in your pom:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.4</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.4</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.testSource>1.5</maven.compiler.testSource>
    <maven.compiler.testTarget>1.5</maven.compiler.testTarget>
</properties>
```

Or by explicit configuration of the compiler plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.4</source>
        <target>1.4</target>
        <testSource>1.5</testSource>
        <testTarget>1.5</testTarget>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```